# Filter Two Dropdowns Based on One Another the Angular Way

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, select, drop-down-menu

I've got two dropdowns. The allowable options in those dropdowns should be filtered based on what's in the other dropdown. Here's the first dropdown:

```
<select ng-model="filter.levelPregenerate">
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option value="assox">Associate's</option>
  <option value="bachx">Bachelor's</option>
  <option value="mastx">Master's</option>
  <option value="doctx">Doctorate</option>
  <option value="nondx">Non-Degree</option>
  <option value="bridx">Bridge</option>
</select>
```

And the second dropdown is an ng-repeat, as follows:

```
<select ng-model="filter.degreeTypePregenerate">
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option ng-repeat="type in degreeType | orderBy:'toString()'">{{type}}</option>
</select>
```

And here's the array being repeated above:

```
$scope.degreeType = ['BA', 'BS', 'MA', 'MBA', 
                     'MDIV', 'MED', 'MFA', 'MPH', 
                     'MS',' DNP', 'EDD', 'PHD', 
                     'EDSPL', 'GRDCERT'];
```

The options in the first and second dropdown should be filtered based on each other. Here's the mapping between the two (how the filter should work):

```
assox: '';
bachx: 'BA, BS';
mastx: 'MA, MBA, MDIV, MED, MFA, MPH, MS';
doctx: 'DNP, EDD, PHD';
nondx: 'EDSPL, GRDCERT';
bridx: ''
```

So, if 'BA' is selected in the second dropdown, 'bachx' should be the only option available in the first dropdown. Conversely, if 'doctx' is selected in the first dropdown, 'DNP', 'EDD', and 'PHD' should be the only select-able options in the second dropdown.

**Here's a Codepen with the full code: http://codepen.io/trueScript/pen/LVZKEo**

I don't think I can simply apply a basic '| filter:foo' to the second dropdown, because it wouldn't know how to filter it. What is the Angular way to do this?

Comment: this question sounds familiar .. did you try typing `[angularjs] dropdown filter` in the search box at the top of this page? hopefully, some relevant question/answers turn up. for example this [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23115771/chaining-multiple-filters-with-angularjs)

Comment: here's another SO Post about [cascading drop down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19314810/angularjs-cascade-dropdown) , do you think that you may have to format the stored data in `$scope.degreeType` to make mapping easier? ...e.g. [{'assoc':'BA'}, {'assoc':'BS'},..etc] as an `array of objects`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up a custom filter and return the values that should be displayed. Two ways of doing it:

Option 1 - If/else

```
angular.module('programApp', [
    'programApp.controllers',
    'programApp.filters'
]);

angular.module('programApp.filters', [])
.filter('dropdownFilter', function() {
    return function(input, degreeTypePregenerate) {

    if (degreeTypePregenerate === 'assox') {
      return [];
    } else if (degreeTypePregenerate === 'bachx') {
      return ['BA', 'BS'];
    }

    // and so on..

    }
});
```

Option 2 - An object (cleaner in my opinion)

```
angular.module('programApp.filters', [])
.filter('dropdownFilter', function() {
    return function(input, degreeTypePregenerate) {

        var degreeType = {
            'assox': [],
            'bachx': ['BA', 'BS']
        };

    return degreeType[degreeTypePregenerate];

    }
});
```

Finally, apply the filter to your ng-repeat, passing in the variable you want to filter by:

```
<option ng-repeat="type in degreeType | orderBy:'toString()' | dropdownFilter:filter.levelPregenerate">{{type}}</option>
```

Working codepen: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLKqzb)

Comment: Very complete answer. Thank you!